# Is it possible to run excel typescript (with a button) without the script run status window popping up

Tags: excel, typescript, excel-automation

I've made a little function for adding/deleting some data via pressing on a button in my table and it all works fine, but every time when the function starts, the script run status window pops up on the right side and just shows the status.
Is it possible to deactivate that so that the window just doesn't show up when the script runs through?

Did the coding and it works fine, I just don't know if it is possible. I also didn't find some documentation about it.